# ASP.NET Core sessions timeout after 10 seconds

Tags: asp.net-core, session, asp.net-session, asp.net-core-configuration

My website sessions timeout every ten seconds in the hosting environment, but works fine in my local development environment. I have been unable to change the timeout.

```cs
services.AddSession(options =>
{
  options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(600);
  options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
  options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
});
```

I have even tried the above configuration, but it's not working; it still times out after ten seconds, even the operations are done.

Comment: even the user is active the session gets timedout after 10 seconds

Comment: What's the  hosting environment? Could you share the more code and the steps that can reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is up to you to write middleware logic that checks if the Session exists and redirect when Session does not exist.

A much better approach is using the standard Cookie Authentication that comes with ASP.NET Core.  It has the redirect feature built-in.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-3.0

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. It turned out to be a third-party library overriding session options.
I had to use dotnet source stepping and breakpoints to indicate which library is creating the problem.

```cs
public OptionsFactory(IEnumerable<IConfigureOptions<TOptions>> setups, IEnumerable<IPostConfigureOptions<TOptions>> postConfigures, IEnumerable<IValidateOptions<TOptions>> validations)
{
    _setups = setups as IConfigureOptions<TOptions>[] ?? new List<IConfigureOptions<TOptions>>(setups).ToArray();
    _postConfigures = postConfigures as IPostConfigureOptions<TOptions>[] ?? new List<IPostConfigureOptions<TOptions>>(postConfigures).ToArray();
    _validations = validations as IValidateOptions<TOptions>[] ?? new List<IValidateOptions<TOptions>>(validations).ToArray();
}
```

Here the `_setups` had two items instead of the one session option I had provided.